# Laptop shutdown frequently after 15 minuts of watching videos

Tags: shutdown, 17.04, crash, automatic

I'm using Ubuntu v17.04.

I don't know if its a bug or something else but my laptop keeps shutting down while watching videos for a long time like about 15min.

I didn't come  across this issue while using my laptop other than watching videos.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Unless the laptop is set to automatically switch off after 15min of inactivity (easy to test) then it's indeed likely to be overheating as @clint_a said.

Answer (score 1):

seems like this is a hardware issue and not a software issue.

Does the laptop feel warn or the fan makes loud noises whilst watching videos?
It could be that the laptop needs to be cleaned internally, or its GPU (especially if it has a discrete GPU) is dying....

Comment: no everything fine.. my laptop doesnt get hot or doesnt make any sounds...